# AWS SAM :: AWS::Serverless::Api "Invalid value for 'Auth' property"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, openapi, aws-serverless, aws-sam

I've managed to define a template for a Lambda behind an API GW authenticated via (dedicated) ApiKey by describing everything in the template and with no OpenApi definition.

The problem arises when trying to introduce Lambda Integrations for accomplishing the mappings: it seems that they can be defined only in the OpenAPI docs which, of course, I cannot manage to make work. Because SAM validation fails complaining about the Auth part.

```
Template provided at '/Users/cionzo/PycharmProjects/my_project/template.yaml' was invalid SAM Template.
Error: [InvalidResourceException('ApiGateway', "Invalid value for 'Auth' property")] ('ApiGateway', "Invalid value for 'Auth' property")
```

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  myToyApp POC
  SAM Template for myToyApp POC

# ====================================
# PARAMETERS SETUP
# ====================================
Parameters:
  StageParam:
    Type: String
    Default: dev
    Description: (Required) Enter dev, test, prod. Default is dev.
    AllowedValues:
      - dev
      - test
      - prod
  ProjectName:
    Type: String
    Default: myToyApp
    Description: (Required) The name of the project
    MinLength: 3
    MaxLength: 50
    AllowedPattern: ^[A-Za-z_-]+$
    ConstraintDescription: "Required. Can be characters, hyphen, and underscore only. No numbers or special characters allowed."

Mappings:
  Stage2Settings:
    LoggingLevel:
      dev: "INFO"
      test: "INFO"
      prod: "ERROR"

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 60

Resources:
  ApiGateway:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub "${ProjectName}_${StageParam}"
      StageName: !Ref StageParam
      MethodSettings:
        - LoggingLevel: !FindInMap [ Stage2Settings, "LoggingLevel", !Ref StageParam ]
          ResourcePath: '/*'      # allows for logging on any resource
          HttpMethod: '*'         # allows for logging on any method
          DataTraceEnabled: true  # Put logs into cloudwatch
          MetricsEnabled: true    # Enable detailed metrics (error 404, latence, ...)
      Auth:
        ApiKeyRequired: true
        UsagePlan:
          CreateUsagePlan: PER_API
          Description: Usage plan for this API
        DefinitionBody:
          openapi: 3.0.0
          info:
            title: "Hello Api"
            version: 0.3.0
            description: "This is an example OpenAPI specification"
            termsOfService: "http://example.com/tos"
            contact:
              email: "example@example.com"
          x-amazon-apigateway-request-validators:
            all:
              validateRequestBody: true
              validateRequestParameters: true
            params:
              validateRequestBody: true
              validateRequestParameters: true
            body:
              validateRequestBody: true
              validateRequestParameters: false
          paths:
            /processData:
              post:
                operationId: processData
                description: Test sam local functionality with API Gateway & Open API



  myToyAppPOCFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: myLambdaCodeFolder/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      FunctionName: !Sub "${ProjectName}_DataProcessor_${StageParam}"
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /processData
            Method: POST
            RestApiId: !Ref ApiGateway





Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  myToyAppPOCApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for myToyAppPOCFunction"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ApiGateway}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${StageParam}/processData/"


  myToyAppPOCFunction:
    Description: "myToyAppPOCFunction Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: "myToyAppPOCFunction"
  myToyAppPOCFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt myToyAppPOCFunctionRole.Arn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Auth` property syntax includes an incorrect property for `DefinitionBody`.

To fix your listed error, unindent that `DefinitionBody` block so its parent is `Properties`, and not `Auth`

```
ApiGateway:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
  Properties:
    Name: !Sub "${ProjectName}_${StageParam}"
    StageName: !Ref StageParam
    MethodSettings:
      - LoggingLevel: !FindInMap [ Stage2Settings, "LoggingLevel", !Ref StageParam ]
        ResourcePath: '/*'      # allows for logging on any resource
        HttpMethod: '*'         # allows for logging on any method
        DataTraceEnabled: true  # Put logs into cloudwatch
        MetricsEnabled: true    # Enable detailed metrics (error 404, latence, ...)
    Auth:
      ApiKeyRequired: true
      UsagePlan:
        CreateUsagePlan: PER_API
        Description: Usage plan for this API
    DefinitionBody:
      openapi: 3.0.0
      info:
        title: "Hello Api"
        version: 0.3.0
        description: "This is an example OpenAPI specification"
        termsOfService: "http://example.com/tos"
        contact:
          email: "example@example.com"
      x-amazon-apigateway-request-validators:
        all:
          validateRequestBody: true
          validateRequestParameters: true
        params:
          validateRequestBody: true
          validateRequestParameters: true
        body:
          validateRequestBody: true
          validateRequestParameters: false
      paths:
        /processData:
          post:
            operationId: processData
            description: Test sam local functionality with API Gateway & Open API
```

For more information on proper syntax check out the docs:

- **AWS::Serverless::Api** , https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html#sam-resource-api-syntax
- **ApiAuth (the Auth prop)** : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-api-apiauth.html#sam-property-api-apiauth-syntax

Comment: Thank you @petey  one last thing: is there a way to avoid replicating path info in Events (among Function properties) other than in OpenApi definition? If I remove the Event section, the ApiGateway does not get authorized to invoke the Lambda...

Comment: @cionzo,  that seems like another really good question.  Can you create one? I'm not 100% I think I grok what you mean about the replication avoidance.